# One-way binding for a textarea in vue js - safe to use `:value`?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make the data update the textarea while user input in the textarea doesn't update the data (hence one-way binding, as supposed to `v-model`'s two way binding.) I've stumbled upon the `:value` attribute, which worked for me. However after searching and testing, it doesn't seem to work under plain HTML and JS. I couldn't find any documentation either, so I was wondering if this is the right way at all. Is this standard, is there a reference on this? Thanks.

Edit: here's a snippet. I want this to be a one way binding because I want to be able to revert the contents of the textarea to its original state, if I chose so. Duplicating the data (which would require a deep object clone for my app) would be unnecessary and wasteful in this case.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    x: "test"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>{{x}}</div>
  Using :value: <br />
  <textarea :value="x"></textarea>
  <br />
  Using v-model: <br />
  <textarea v-model="x"></textarea>
  <br />
  Using value: (this doesn't work) <br />
  <textarea value="test"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post some more of your code so we can give a decent explanation with your specific use case?

Comment: (I'm guessing that's the reason for your downvote too)

Comment: Hi. I updated the question with code and a use case, though I don't see how this would help since it's not quite implementation specific

Comment: thanks! There are a few different use cases I was considering in my head after reading your question so seeing the code helped clear that up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Remember that](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) `v-model` is basically the same as:

```
<textarea
   :value="something"
   @input="something = $event.target.value"
></textarea>
```

So when you do the `:value` instead of `v-model` you are only doing the one way binding and *not* getting the `@input` back out, thus you get the one-way binding instead of the two-way binding you get with `v-model`. If your goal is to get one-way binding, then this is certainly the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking the `value` property mentioned in the doc was just for javascript, but now I think vue has some extra javascript under the hood. That clears things up.